# How do I set up fulltext?

Tags: php, mysql

Why doesn't this query give me any results?

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs 
WHERE MATCH(title, description) AGAINST('+php' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I have `PHP` word in both title and description rows.

Maybe because it has `php` in almost every row?

Comment: Did you add fulltext index to your table? And did you use MyISAM engine?

Comment: is the ft_min_word_len 3, by default its 4 and php is a 3 letter word.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your table definition. But in my opinion, you should check

- Your MySQL engine whether it is MyISAM or not (version 5.6 for InnobDB is OK).
- Fulltext index for your two conlumn title and description

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs
(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(200),
    description TEXT,
    FULLTEXT (title,body)
)ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a minimum word length setting in mysql, which default to 4,
but PHP is three chars

The configuration you can take a look

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

After update the configuration, restart mysql daemon and re-built the full-text index

details :- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html